# Facebook on Android — Debug popup Hashkey keep appear

Tags: android, facebook, hash, air, popup

I'm trying to add the Facebook API in my application. I build it in ActionScript3-AIR to proceed an export on iOS/Android and use the GoViral API to apply the connection with Facebook.

After the creation of the application on Facebook Developer, it works on iOS, but not on Android. 
When this line is read `GoViral.goViral.initFacebook( XXXXXXX )`, on Android, the application show a popup which display the Key Hashes *Here, the screenshot:*

[image: screenshot1]

Then, nothing happen. The connexion don't seem to be done and, if I try an authentication with `GoViral.goViral.authenticateWithFacebook( "user_likes,user_photos,publish_actions" )` it does nothing. And by that, I really mean nothing in the way that it don't even return the `GVFacebookEvent.FB_LOGIN_FAILED` event.

I used the "Mail It" button on this popup. Took the hash key and pasted it in the Android section of my application in the Facebook Developer *Here, the screenshot:*

[image: screenshot2]

But, nothing changes and the popup always appears.

After that and by the results of some google research, I've try to make my own Hash Key, helped by some tutorials. The Key has been generated but didn't correct anything about the popup.

So, actually, I'm a little confuse about this issue.
Especially as I've try to put another fake App ID in the `initFacebook` method : the popup continues to appear. So I wonder if it can really see it.

For information, I created the application project on the Google Developers Console.
The manifest I use to apply the Facebook API is this one :

```
    <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="12"/>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" 
    android:label="Login"/>
    </application>
```

Thanks a lot to help me to fix this issue.

------ EDIT ------

I found the problem about the Debug Pop-up with the Hash Key. It was relative to the GoViral API which ( I didn't know this ) has two version : One normal and one for the debug which always makes appear the hash key in a pop-up at connection.

The Facebook connection still not working, but it's sound to be another problem so I can say this problem is solved.

Comment: Please remove your solution from the question - it should be put down in an answer box instead of edited into the question. You can then accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution which is way simple than I imagined. In the sources of GoViral, there was two ANE, I used the one which was makes for debug. It makes appear the popup to give us the hashkey. After what, we have to put the other ane to make it work.